# Android - How to design options like in play store

Tags: android, android-layout

I wanted to design options like in Google play store. Please see this image

[image]

Options displayed such as top charts, games, family which are scrollable.

I will have dynamic number of options. Any pointers, help.

Thank you

Comment: what options are you talking about? Do you mean the UI of TopCharts, Games, Family?

Comment: if u are tallking about the game,family ... these are simple imagebutton or textview with different background .Just changing the shorting order

Comment: @pratik, You can check the answer posted over here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, You wish to design the capsules like the one metnioned over there **Top Charts, Family, Games and so on** with the options being dynamic in number...

**1. Designing the green Capsules for textViews**

First, create a rectangular shape with a big radius and green color...

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="@color/greenColorCustom" />

    <corners android:radius="30dp" />

</shape>
```

Assign this shape as a background to your TextView.

```
               <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/capsule_rectangle_green"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="15dp"
                    android:text="TOP CHARTS"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
```

**2. Dynamic number of options...**

As for the dynamic number of options, if you want those list of options to be horizontally scrollable (I assume), You can use a RecyclerView with horizontal Orientation By setting the LayoutManager.

```
 recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager
(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
```

Either ways, I want you to try yourself first. Therefore, I am adding only a snippet of code.